# How can I integrate these commands in python?

Tags: python, linux

I have three commands, I can use them in Terminal.
like:
    `

```
cd /home/john

hbatch john_v001.hip

render /out/john -f 1 10 -i 3`
```

how to use python script to do it in Terminal?
like type -> 
`r john -f 1 10 -i 3`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to call your external processes.

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['hbatch', '/home/john/john_v001.hip'])
check_call(['render', '/home/john/out/john', '-f', '1', '10', '-i', '3'])
```

Comment: I edit the code, you can see it clearly. this will work? thank you

Comment: If you are using a python version that does not have subprocess yet, you could also use os.spawnv() (and the related commands)

Comment: sorry, i am new,i don't really understand your idea, can you make it simple, or explain it in code